# How to limit and control the number of click on button per day or per hour in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

How to limit and control the number of click on button per day (or per hour) in ReactJs

any help please

Comment: Per hour beginning on first time clicked?

Comment: Provide more information on how you want to implement it

Comment: for example : if a condidate want to apply for a job , he just be able to apply for 5 times only per day and the button of apply will not be able to be clicked  and he will wait 24h to can apply (click the button) again

Comment: @webdev This is something that you must validate in your private code (back end / server / etc.). You must assume that the user of your client (React) app has complete control over the view, state (JavaScript), network requests, etc., so any attempts to restrict actions on the client can be subverted/bypassed by the user.

Comment: You could store the initial click time in localStorage and then compare against it. But as @jsejcksn said, anyone with some knowledge can go remove that. Alternatively you could use redis in your backend to track it by storing the ip address and initial click time (assuming a user can click it without having an account on your site) . Otherwise if they're logged in, just make a field in your DB

Comment: so it's impossible to do that in react ?

Answer (score 1):

> How to limit and control the number of click on button per day (or per hour) in ReactJs

You can't restrict this in React. I explained this in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72986648/how-to-limit-and-control-the-number-of-click-on-button-per-day-or-per-hour-in-re#comment128912523_72986648):

> This is something that you must validate in your private code (back end / server / etc.). You must assume that the user of your client (React) app has complete control over the view, state (JavaScript), network requests, etc., so any attempts to restrict actions on the client can be subverted/bypassed by the user.

So, you'll need to validate this in other private code that's not running in your client app.

---

With that out of the way, and acknowledging that the user can manipulate the state of your client app, let's explore an implementation of the kind of quota you asked about on the client (just for fun) with a custom hook: `useQuota`:

> Note that the hook doesn't use timers directly because timers on the order of hours/days are imprecise/unreliable.

[Code in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=107&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMAiB5AsnAMyghDgHIpUMBaAExIHo0AbYJAOxjIG4AoUSLDgBvXnDi0kBFAFdm8FAGdEVGABoxcAMowowDLgiSN4mYqQBhFM2YAjdAGsTcM0mQFnrnShhJnMAE8wJBV0GABRZiQQDnVeAF9CYlIKVR5eXkDguABFGQgYFABVRRQAczckRTl4AF4RTQYAKibNOCa4AHUACw44AIgZKDhKEBRgdgmyuAA3axkQgHdgGzgJtEolEPYkAA8YADo2js6V5jhrRZQA5VsQlDhMHxCZdijFZQGhuABHfMK4KwQMB4MBlAADAAM4KO4naDE0O32AEl2BtUOYAFyPZ5wAA+cHYcmYfEaLTgADkIOxqDsyj5gDMQhNfBVhk0EeJRuNJuwytiiSA7lBSeJmidujBesNoISCnApSE-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-ISSCGcZSBHYZADUcC-eRcDubFYk5UtcC3jYW7FVdPo1KhgalBUIY1K2JHae9n2bOYzjadyExTNii3wO5K1TTNzXdJTcJGlUijYgAhL1-U6nq7O2hdQXoY43pVDU53iPEYEUYhLqOGB9Ngf+3lvsB-nMGBCP2XR7HnfEGTPmiPlwAAgmAYDddhoQYJE0SxFpOnsLDtlQMitDuFx5juJ6kLnZowUUbYMgwDA1LLns6g7TAABC4eR+w0f7A9H52b4npkBSMdkDLruwxREwEBADG7aipfp9xzzZxYrBugqvRwGHEfUgqEAtweEz51uDAMNou1NyE9Md3AAAsFyvvBFZMlAARwHWijB1d1L1-o7r1K4X6en+q2AVrk7YnWSAAMwq852Lj3L3VY-IeHRsThfwMIpNouTfgjNEPJTAxMhalzRI9Q74wHRtuAeVg0RIHOGASgMwMxmAVGuKA20WCoCgCJQYMBkrIK9u4A4aAhiUE4EHbS-c4ColoPoXEw1drSinj5ZQ1N2DbUYonNuKcY6SzGDTPkHpaj1HrIDMgnRxhcBRuQXO+xe6i3EFEeAMgwC0GeLQSund6jgi0P-Y03M4AABJhCcw+HAYRugFhkAkWQaQzBzBkHiOCDqijlG+FUewUucAIYaLAsgHhvJ+T6OEMwqY9iwHAC6uNGOZMMRIAjE-UwSiVFqI8V4ykMcTxfXMBcGA2IDFvwyZWSODkICKyQCJHQeg+S4RCdtMUA8tBDweB7MeTjcSKhbknduvh9jDyBt02yPTerpI-svbSGM3bwBAIoIonAVhSI+u-aJrY8kfyrLtESGl3Kg1MgZLaoykExE9t7KQBCiHO3qIxTB4d1IPzjuw5OqdsE5zznlOAkzpnpmYHMqJWwC6y1kXHNRnoWkuLUQXOWWE5K7UUt1bavEqEzEjDUuAcLGSRmECXCA8ReIMHhYivZvFW7JxENFA4wg14NwcPEeIaLCVRxjlihgtL2B4rhNi3FmgjYZGCpsDACBzQuWQGEGcBDNi+D5QUT09BCExE4KsiIUQZUJwCF7bOxACj5x5kHHlMBxWHGIZIKAP5xC8XKfoGAhhJAsuNVbG2DAWXYtNQYIwSBEXnSAA)

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.18.8/babel.min.js"></script><script>Babel.registerPreset('tsx', {presets: [[Babel.availablePresets['typescript'], {allExtensions: true, isTSX: true}]]});</script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="tsx,react">

// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
// import {
//   StrictMode,
//   useCallback,
//   useRef,
//   useState,
//   type ReactElement,
// } from 'react';

// This Stack Overflow snippet demo uses UMD modules
// instead of the commented import statments above
const {
  StrictMode,
  useCallback,
  useRef,
  useState,
} = React;

type QuotaUsageResult = {
  /**
   * When your remaining value will increase next.
   * Will always be a Date unless your quota limit is `0`.
   */
  nextIncrease: Date | null;

  /** Non-negative integer */
  remaining: number;

  /** Whther or not the quota usage succeeded */
  success: boolean;
};

type QuotaCallback = (result: QuotaUsageResult) => void;

type QuotaOptions = {
  /** Milliseconds. e.g. 10 seconds = `10_000` */
  expirationInterval: DOMHighResTimeStamp;

  /** Non-negative integer */
  limit: number;
};

function useQuota (
  {expirationInterval, limit}: QuotaOptions,
  callback: QuotaCallback,
): () => void {
  const [timeStamps, setTimeStamps] = useState<EpochTimeStamp[]>([]);

  return useCallback(() => {
    const now = Date.now();
    const timeStampLimit = now - expirationInterval;
    const notExpired = [...timeStamps.filter(ts => ts > timeStampLimit), now];
    const quotaExceeded = notExpired.length > limit;
    if (quotaExceeded) while (notExpired.length > limit) notExpired.pop();
    setTimeStamps(notExpired);

    const [oldest] = notExpired;
    const nextIncrease = oldest ? new Date(now + oldest - timeStampLimit) : null;

    const result: QuotaUsageResult = {
      nextIncrease,
      remaining: limit - notExpired.length,
      success: !quotaExceeded,
    };

    callback(result);
  }, [callback, limit, expirationInterval, timeStamps]);
}

function App (): ReactElement {
  const timerIdRef = useRef(0);

  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState('Next');
  const [info, setInfo] = useState('Click the button to begin');

  // Set the limit to 4 actions, every 10s
  const onClick = useQuota({expirationInterval: 10e3, limit: 4}, (result) => {
    const {nextIncrease, remaining, success} = result;

    // Cancel previous timer
    clearTimeout(timerIdRef.current);

    // Indicate whether actions remain
    setButtonText(remaining === 0 ? 'Wait' : 'Next');

    let updatedInfo = `Success: ${success ? 'true' : 'false'}`;
    updatedInfo += `, Remaining: ${remaining}`;

    if (nextIncrease) {
      updatedInfo += `, Next increase at: ${nextIncrease.toLocaleTimeString()}`;
      // Set a timer to update the button text the next time the quota increases
      const msUntilNextIncrease = nextIncrease.getTime() - Date.now();
      timerIdRef.current = setTimeout(() => setButtonText('Next'), msUntilNextIncrease);
    }

    setInfo(updatedInfo);
  },
);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{info}</div>
      <button {...{onClick}}>{buttonText}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!);

reactRoot.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);

</script>
```